# Don't prompt for opening certain external apps in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome prompts me before opening external apps. Is it possible to add certain apps to an allowlist (e.g., Zoom, Notion) so that I'm not prompted each time?

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are referring to protocol handlers - this is the message that says "Are you sure you want to open this link in ?"

If so, try this:

- Quit Google Chrome.
- With Finder selected, hit the Shift-⌘-G and enter
  the folder address ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome.
- Open the "Default" folder, and open the "Preferences" file in a text
  editor like Text Editor.
- Search for the phrase “excluded_schemes,”
  which houses your list of protocol handler preferences in the text
  file.
- Search for the protocol (like “itmss” for iTunes, or
  “slack” for Slack) and change its state from “false” to “true,”
  taking care not to remove any punctuation.
- Save the file, and re-open
  Chrome.

** This only works if you've previously left "Always use this app for this filetype" unchecked, and may not work for all versions of Chrome  ***

[image: go to folder image]